# How to change all True values in list on False and vice versa

Tags: python, list

I have a list consists of True and False values, and I can't find easy way to change all True values in list on False and vice versa.

For example I have:

```
array = [True, False, False, True, True]
```

I need to get

```
array = [False, True, True, False, False]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can invert the array using list comprehension:

```
array = [not elem for elem in array]
```

Comment: And totally PEP 20 compliant: Simple is better than complex.

Answer (score 2):

Use a simple list comprehension

```
>>> array = [True, False, False, True, True]
>>> [False  if i else True for i in array]
[False, True, True, False, False]
```

Else you can also try (Python2)

```
>>> map(lambda x:not x ,array)
```

And for those who hate `lambda`

```
>>> import operator
>>> map(operator.not_ ,array)
```